# Adding and Insert a column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataframe in where I have pulled out 1% of the dataset to create a new column and assign a value to it.  Now, I would like to add that data back to the intial dataframe.  How would I go about that?

Thanks

I have tried using the left join, but it seems to be adding more row than inserting it back again.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your python code. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you use `merge` or `join`? If you use `merge`, use `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`. Please provide an example.

Comment: From this description it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish and how. It'd help a great deal if you mocked some sample data to illustrate your before and after.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df
df1 = df.sample(frac=0.05, random_state=42, replace=True)
df1["Flag"] = Y
df_merged=pd.merge(df,df1, on='xxx', how='left')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use index alignment:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df1 = df.sample(frac=0.05, random_state=42, replace=True)
df1["Flag"] = 'Y'

#                            HERE --v              --v
df_merged = pd.merge(df, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

But a more straightforward way is:

```
df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.05).index, 'Flag'] = 'Y'
```

With `numpy`:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df.index.isin(df.sample(frac=0.05).index), 'Y', 'N')
```

Comment: How do I delete the additional duplicate columns created by this join.  So, basically what I am seeing now is A_x, B_x, A_y, B_y with same data and I want to remove 'A_y, B_y...'  Thanks

Comment: Just select the right column: `pd.merge(df, df1['Flag'], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`